# Video to full modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I am inserting YouTube videos in my website with iframes and I need to make the video almost full screen and the background white (like a full screen mode). I know how to make both, but I cant move the video with javascript from his container to a new one without stoping so how can i do it?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you're using Bootstrap. I think you should be able to use it if you arent using Bootstrap too.
YTModal helps you play Youtube videos in a popup window based jQuery and Twitter **Bootstrap** modal component. It also requires jQuery YouTubeDefaultImageLoader.js to insert Youtube video iframes with post images into your web page

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Youtube-Video-Modal-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3-YTModal.html